# Please suggest SharePoint 2013 certifications

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, designer-workflow, certification, 70-667

Currently i am working on SharePoint 2013 environment as SharePoint Administrator

Have done 70-667 Microsoft Office SharePoint Configuring and 70-536 Microsoft .NET frame work application development  certification

Please suggest me SharePoint 2013 certifications & how about 70-331 & 70-332, Which one should go first?

Comment: 70-331 is the 2013 equivalent of 70-667. 70-332 is the Advanced configuration cert. For more see here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c5f15c8e-a6dc-4a8b-9265-ff1dc75653e8/what-is-the-sharepoint-2013-certification-path-developers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## MCSE SharePoint

If you want to strive towards a certified [MCSE: SharePoint Solution Expert](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx#fbid=Jx5ARZm0rcG) , then look closer to these exams:

- [Installing and Configuring Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-410.aspx)
- [Administering Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-411.aspx)
- [Configuring Advanced Windows Server 2012 Services](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-412.aspx)
- **[Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-331.aspx)**
- **[Advanced Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-332.aspx)**

[image]

## MCSM SharePoint

This is the baseline for the next step: The [MCSM: SharePoint Solutions Master](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsm-sharepoint-certification.aspx) which contains the five previous and the following four exams:

- **[Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?ID=70-488)**
- **[Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?ID=70-489)**
- MCSM SharePoint Knowledge Exam
- MCSM SharePoint Lab Exam

[image]
[image]

## MCSD SharePoint

The other track to go is the [MCSD: SharePoint Applications Solutions Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx)

- [Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-480.aspx)
- [Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-486.aspx)
- **[Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?ID=70-488)**
- **[Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?ID=70-489)**

[image]

## Conclusion

Either of these exams can be taken separately, but go with 70-331 before 70-332 and 70-488 before 70-489. This will make your appearance in the community stronger if you take exams in the "right" order.

Comment: On a related note: http://www.wictorwilen.se/microsoft-advanced-certification-mca-mcsm-mcm---the-end-of-an-era MCSM will no longer be a certification level

Comment: @RobertLindgren Sad really, if true. So far the MCSM looks pretty valid, since its still present on microsoft.com. Looks like another one of those days when MS don't inform their users what is really going on. :(

Comment: @Ashrafkhan You're welcome! :)

Comment: Is it compulsory to follow the sequence ?
Means can i directly go for "Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013" (070-331)

Comment: @Ashrafkhan No, not at all. I'm doing the 70-331 next monday without having the Windows Server certificates (70-410, 70-411, 70-412) first.

Answer (score 0):

i believe 70-331 should go first and the resource material I am using for that is 
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exam-Ref-70-331-Solutions-SharePoint/dp/0735678081/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1391696270&sr=8-1&keywords=70-331

I will post you update , when I have more resources for this exam 70-331, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass 70-331 and then you can proceed for 70-332. because 70-331 is a pre-requisite for 70-332